# Set a JTextArea to act like a log

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Hello how could I make it so that the JTextArea (log) act as a log and display the text that is input and output?

Here is what I have so far.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String mess = message.getText();
    System.out.println(mess);

}
```

Here are the vars

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea log;
private javax.swing.JTextField message;
// End of variables declaration
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: use [`Append(string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`append()` will append the data to the end.

Instead, you need to first get the text using the `getText()`, concatenate the log to it, then use `setText()` with the newly formed error message.

So, conceptually, your new text is :

> error log + previously displayed text

**SSCCE**

```
package stack;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AppendMyError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] errorMsg = {"NullPointerException",
                                   "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException",
                                   "OutOfMemoryException"
                                  };


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Useless Title");
                final JButton errorBtn = new JButton("Click");
                final JTextArea errorLog = new JTextArea(30,30);
                final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(errorLog);
                final Random rand = new Random();

                jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(errorBtn);
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);

                errorBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        String currentText = errorLog.getText();
                        String newError = new Date() + " " +  errorMsg[rand.nextInt(errorMsg.length)];
                        String newTextToAppend = newError + "\n" + currentText;
                        errorLog.setText(newTextToAppend);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

If you look at the time, the newer messages are at the top.

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there away to make it so that the new message goes below the old?

Comment: In that case, just use `append()` rather than all the mumbo-jumbo I have done.

Comment: @Fusion Just give me an example of what you want to do :)

Answer (score 3):

you can say

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String mess = message.getText();
    System.out.println(mess);
    log.append(mess);

}
```

`append()` function Appends the given text to the end of the document.

Comment: I have tried that, that only will display the most recent message. I want it to stay there and do it line by line, just like System.out.println will.

Comment: @Fusion If I am not mistaken, you want the newer log messages to appear at the top rather than be appended at the bottom, right ?

Comment: @LittleChild: no generally new data should be append to end. as an example, open a jboss log file with your favorite file editor. you can see log will append to end

Comment: @lakshman As far as I remember, the OP had said like how `System.out.println()` would display :-/

Answer (score 1):

JTextArea has a `append(String str)` method, so try:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String mess = message.getText();
    System.out.println(mess);
    log.append(mess);
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Fusion. Are you sure you are not creating a new log when you use the `append(String str)` method? In the above comments you say it just changes it, but the append should as per the description:<br><br>Appends the given text to the end of the document.